# python: PID to X11 Window ID using XResQueryClientIds

Tags: python, x11, xcb

*Note:* This  is a continuation of the answer to [What process created this X11 window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84981) from unix.stackexchange. That answer mentions `XResQueryClientIds` from [X-Resource v1.2 extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/resourceproto/resproto.txt). I'd like to know how to use it.

How can I use [python's xcffib module](https://github.com/tych0/xcffib) to find all X11 window IDs associated with a provided PID (assuming no race conditions; windows or processes aren't being created or destroyed).

I don't know much about X11, the [XCB API documentation](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/XcbApi/) seems incomplete, and the [auto-generated xcffib python bindings](https://github.com/tych0/xcffib) are undocumented. From what I gather, I need:

1. Create a connection: `xcb_connect`
2. Get the extension: ?undocumented?
3. Query the extension: ?`xcb_get_extension_data` mentions "?QueryExtension requests"
4. Get the query response: `xcb_get_extension_data`
5. Use the [extension documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/resourceproto/resproto.txt) and the [protocol stub API](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/ProtocolStubApi/) to unpack the response.

Comment: If my answer helped you please do mark it as accepted. I noticed that you've been on SO but haven't yet given any feedback on my answer.

Answer (score 5):

> assuming no race conditions; windows or processes aren't being created or destroyed

Assuming is bad if you know that the assumption doesn't hold. Luckily, you don't need this assumption. Just use `xcb_grab_server` and `xcb_ungrab_server` around your operations and this won't be an issue.

Now, as for `XResQueryClientIds`, you can actually just type in `man xcb_res_query_client_ids`. XCB just provides this, no need to actually query the extension. Here's a sample program. Compile it with `gcc -lxcb -lxcb-res main.c` and then execute it by passing a window ID as the only argument (e.g., `./a.out 0x2c00004`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/res.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int screen;
    xcb_connection_t *conn = xcb_connect(NULL, &screen);

    xcb_res_client_id_spec_t spec = {0};
    spec.client = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    spec.mask = XCB_RES_CLIENT_ID_MASK_LOCAL_CLIENT_PID;

    xcb_generic_error_t *err = NULL;
    xcb_res_query_client_ids_cookie_t cookie = xcb_res_query_client_ids(conn, 1, &spec);
    xcb_res_query_client_ids_reply_t *reply = xcb_res_query_client_ids_reply(conn, cookie, &err);

    if (reply == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Uh-Oh! :(\n");
        return -1;
    }

    uint32_t *pid = NULL;
    xcb_res_client_id_value_iterator_t it = xcb_res_query_client_ids_ids_iterator(reply);
    for (; it.rem; xcb_res_client_id_value_next(&it)) {
        spec = it.data->spec;
        if (spec.mask & XCB_RES_CLIENT_ID_MASK_LOCAL_CLIENT_PID) {
            pid = xcb_res_client_id_value_value(it.data);
            break;
        }
    }

    free(reply);
    xcb_disconnect(conn);

    fprintf(stderr, "PID: %d\n", *pid);
}
```

To give proper attribution, I didn't know any of this myself either, I just googled for the XCB function name and came across [this](https://github.com/charles-l/dwm/blob/03c8a9e2e0ece49c4fbedcb3cec03a21825763d3/patches/dwm-6.1-swallowing.diff). To understand the individual parts I suggest reading the Xlib documentation of it. XCB is often rather… "under-documented", as you've noticed, but it's really just the same as Xlib with other slightly different names for the most part.

Comment: Not really what I asked for, but helpful. So many problems with xcffib: 1] 0.1 (fedora 23) connect is broken, even with manual xauth 2] tried packing structs manually, which is the *wrong way* 3] many ways to do the same thing, most of them the *wrong way* 4] no docs 5] 0.4.2 (current) has change that breaks compatibility with xlib (should be fixed in next release). Literally ever line I tried had some problem, be it by me (documentation), from an old version, from bad patch, or from a bad protocol.

Comment: Anyway with all these problems I was going to switch to libxcb (c), but since the [X-Resource protocol doesn't match the specification](https://github.com/tych0/xcffib/issues/71), `xcb_res_query_client_ids_reply_t` is full of junk (read-out-of-bounds). The patch fixes this for all the bindings, so now *xcffib* works perfectly, now that I know what I'm doing.

Comment: I see you've put quite some effort into debugging. Cool!

Comment: This is awesome. Figuring this stuff on my own could've easily taken me days.